# Por que devo utilizar a palavra-chave typeof para atribuir uma fonte de dados a um BindingSource.DataSource?

Tags: c#, .net

Por exemplo:

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource(); 

bs.DataSource = typeof(object);
```

Por qual motive devo usar `typeof(object)` ao invés de somente `object` ou mesmo `"object"`?

***edit:***
Como outras pessoas pediram, aí está o código onde vi pela primeira vez o uso da palavra-chave `typeof`, e nesse caso foi usada com um `BindingSource`.
O código foi encontrado [aqui](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24656/A-Detailed-Data-Binding-Tutorial), e sim, o código funciona.

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();                              //**

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bs.DataSource = typeof(Airplane);                                //**
    bs.Add(new Airplane("Boeing 747", 800));
    bs.Add(new Airplane("Airbus A380", 1023));
    bs.Add(new Airplane("Cessna 162", 67));

    grid.DataSource = bs;                                            //**
    grid.AutoGenerateColumns = true; // create columns automatically //**
    txtModel.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "Model");                  //**
}
```

Comment: Eu acho que não precisa, olha o exemplo aqui: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Em todos os casos que utilizei a propriedade [`BindingSource.DataSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx) foi com um objeto que continha dados, até porque esse é o objetivo dessa propriedade, definir uma fonte de dados que será utilizada para fazer um *binding* em alguma parte do formulário.

Passar apenas uma instância de `System.Type` para o tipo `Object` para dentro da propriedade `BindingSource.DataSource` - que é o que você está fazendo ao utilizar o operador [`typeof`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx) em `bs.DataSource = typeof(object);` - "está errado".

O motivo de eu ter dito "está errado" é que não ficou claro na sua pergunta onde você está planejando utilizar essa instância de `BindingSource`, ela poderia estar sendo utilizada por exemplo por um controle *third party*, algo que não estivesse entre os controles padrões do Windows Forms, e nesse caso a mameira como ele foi implementado poderia variar.

Answer (score 2):

> Porque devo user a palavra-chave “typeof” para setar um DataSource em um Databinding?

**Você não deve.** Não sei da onde você tirou isso, mas me parece não fazer sentido nenhum. Não há como dar mais detalhes, pois você não especificou da onde tirou esse exemplo, o contexto que está inserido e também só há duas linhas de código. Talvez isso sirva para algum propósito específico e você não tenha percebido, mas há a possibilidade de ser apenas falta de conhecimento de quem fez o exemplo.

Pesquisando um pouco eu vi que isso é um "truque" para deixar o `DataSource` vazio, porque caso você faça `bindingSource.DataSource = null` receberá uma `System.ArgumentException`.

<sub>Eu não sei ao certo o porquê disso funcionar para limpar o DataSource, mas vou continuar a procurar e editarei a resposta quando tiver algo concreto.</sub>

---

> Por qual motive devo usar typeof(object) ao invés de somente object ou mesmo "object"?

Como eu já disse, não sei o porquê desse "truque", mas vou te explicar a diferença entre esses dois.

`typeOf(object)` retorna o `Type` daquilo que foi passado como argumento. Enquanto `object` é o tipo propriamente dito, digo, ao fazer `typeOf(T)` você está devolvendo uma instância de `System.Type`, diferente de passar direto um tipo (como `T` ou `object`).

Answer (score 0):

Você deve atribuir um objeto a `bs.DataSource`. Com o `typeof(object)` você faz a "conversão" da Classe `object` para um objeto do tipo `Type`. Utilizar apenas o `object` seria interpretado pelo compilador como uma declaração a um objeto da classe `object` ou um possível cast, mas não a referencia da classe que você precisa.

Seria algo como

```
   object obj = new object();
   if (obj.GetType() == typeof(object)) { } //isso roda

   if (obj.GetType() == object) { } //isso não
```